# Prevent mixing of console output and written text

Tags: c++, stdout

I have a C++ console application that prints some output constantly while it also accepts commands (using `std::cin`) from the user - output and input happen in separate threads.
If I write a text while some output appears the written text is mixed with application output. How can I prevent this behaviour?
[image: The console]

To solve this problem, I need to display the program **one line above** the line where the text is typed. I'd inspire myself in Minecraft Bukkit server's solution - however I need the same for C++.

[image: desired behaviour]

Comment: Well, what is the desired behaviour? It's quite natural that this happens. If you want something like a console chat client (`irssi` for example), look into a library like `ncurses` instead of trying to patch it together with `cin`/`cout` only.

Comment: You may use some lock...

Comment: @Jarod42 That doesn't sound like a great idea. In the example of a chat program that would mean that once you start typing, you miss *all* new messages until you press enter, and only then see them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the output to appear while things are being typed, you'll need some screen control facilities to have the output go somewhere different than the input area. If I were tasked to implement something like this writing to a terminal I would refresh my [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) experience. I realize you are on a Windows console and I have no idea if the Windows console is capable of the screen control needed to make it happen.

You can possibly tie custom stream buffers into `std::cin` and `std::cout` using the curses functionality under the hood but it may not be worth it. In any case, it isn't entirely trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There's a windows port of ncurses called pdcurses. But if you are using visual studio there's a simple function provided called SetConsoleCursorPosition()

Comment: And I may use that function to put the cursor one line below the `std::cout`s output?